# how to create centralised database using mysql and link to a frontend in netbeans

Tags: mysql, database, netbeans-platform

I have installed   netbeans and mysql .How to create centralised  database  using  mysql and  link to a frontend in netbeans?

Comment: Explanation might help others to understand.

Comment: please clear you question. what do you mean by "centralised database" in netbeans

Answer (score 0):

netbeans have a database [tool](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mysql.html). This tool is like  phpmyadmin.